# Finding inverse $Z$ Transformation of a LTI system and switching of input output signal regarding to difference equation

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform, homework, differential-equation

I have 2 stuffs that are bothering me:
I have the equation:
$y[n]=8x[n]-2x[n-2]-x[n-4]$
When $x[n]$ input and $y[n]$ output.
Now, the system is swapped, $x[n]$ output and $y[n]$ input
The difference equation is the same regarding the first system and the swapped system, right? since the only difference is in the transfer function that if the old system had $H(z)$, this one will be $G(z)=\frac 1 {H(z)}$.
Am I right here??
If so, I need to find the new impulse response $g[n]$. I thought about doing inverse $Z$ transform, but it seems problematic since I will get:
$G(z)=\frac 1 {8-2z^{-2}-z^{-4}}$ and the Z inverse transform is not really possible, it is calculations on calculation and it seems weird.
Is there any other way instead of brute force? it just does not seem quite right to do it that way.

Comment: You did it exactly right. "Z inverse transform is not really possible," Why do you think this? This is a perfectly well behaved and stable system. All the poles are inside the unit circle. Your math is correct, it's your intuition that's wrong.

Comment: Hmm, is not this filter an IIR basically? it is not stable as we know, The poles are not at the unit circle, you will get: $(8-2z^{-2}-z^{-4})=(2-z^{-2})(4+z^{-2})=(\sqrt(2)-z^{-1})(\sqrt(2)+z^{-1})$and multiplied by the other one. the poles are outside the unit circle.

I am talking about the $G(z)$, about the second question**

Comment: sorry forgot to tag @Hilmar

Comment: I think I managed to solve it. got to a pretty hard, was very hard equations, but I got to something. I just did residue theorem with all 4 poles. hope it is good :)

Comment: It sure is an IIR filter. The inverse of an FIR filter is indeed an IIR filter (specifically an all-pole filter). Here the poles are at $\pm \sqrt{0.5}$ and $\pm 0.5j$

Comment: Oh yea, I was a little confused about which filter you asked before, that is why I suddenly understood.
But the question is, is it supposed to be very "ugly solution"? I mean, residue of 4 functions, a very "ugly" function. There is not supposed to be any trick to it maybe? Or the professor just wanted to make us work hard ( because such exercises will never be at test, atleast I hope so ).
And again, thanks for the help!!

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "ugly". The inverse is a very simple and well behaved IIR filter. It can be implemented with a few simple lines of code. It does not have any stability or numerical noise issues.  As far as "real world" IIR filter go, this one is about as easy as it get

Comment: Oh sorry, its not by code, more in like calculating myself. But yea, I thought it was way harder then it seems :)
Thanks!!